# how to get the actual label value/text of a radio button created by dom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

basically im trying to get an alert box with the actual label (selected one either Edit or Delete) using getElementById... created by dom but if i uncomment codes after `alert(a)` and delete `alert(a)` it doesnt even create the buttons for me.. any idea how it can be done or what i did wrong?

```
<HTML>  
<HEAD>  
<TITLE> New Document </TITLE>  
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function createRadio(){  
var objDiv = document.getElementById("radioDiv");  

    var radioItem1 = document.createElement("input");  
    radioItem1.type = "radio";  
    radioItem1.name = "radioGrp";  
    radioItem1.id = "rad1";  
    radioItem1.value = "myradio1";  

//        radioItem1.defaultChecked = true;   
//        radioItem1.checked = true;  

    var radioItem2 = document.createElement("input");  
    radioItem2.type = "radio";  
    radioItem2.name = "radioGrp";  
    radioItem2.id = "rad2";  
    radioItem2.value = "myradio2";  
//        var pA= prompt("Type name for 1");
//        var pB= prompt("Type name for 2");
    var objTextNode1 = document.createTextNode("Edit");  
    var objTextNode2 = document.createTextNode("Delete");  

    var objLabel = document.createElement("label");  
    objLabel.htmlFor = radioItem1.id;  
    objLabel.appendChild(radioItem1);  
    objLabel.appendChild(objTextNode1);  

    var objLabel2 = document.createElement("label");  
    objLabel2.htmlFor = radioItem2.id;  
    objLabel2.appendChild(radioItem2);  
    objLabel2.appendChild(objTextNode2);  


    objDiv.appendChild(objLabel);  
    objDiv.appendChild(objLabel2);  

}   

function test()
{
//    var a = document.getElementById("radioDiv").firstChild;


var a = document.getElementById("radioDiv").firstChild;
alert(a);
//    if (a=="Edit")
//    {
//        alert("Edit");
//    }
//    else if (a=="Delete")
//    {
//        alert("Delete");
//    }
//    else()
//    {
//        alert("Try Again");
//    }
}

</SCRIPT>  
</HEAD>  

<BODY>  

<BUTTON onclick="createRadio()">Create Radio Buttons</BUTTON>
<BUTTON onclick="test()">Alert</BUTTON>
<div id="radioDiv"></div>  
</BODY>  
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(EDIT) Ok, take a look at this! And try to code future problems with this technique: Generic, short functions and comments. Good Luck!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        /**
           * Create a group of radiobuttons
           * @param whereToAttach Div to attach generated things
           * @param groupname Name for the group
           * @param options Array of options ["one","two",...
           */

          function createRadioGroup(whereToAttach, groupname, options) {

              var objDiv = document.getElementById(whereToAttach);
              objDiv.innerHTML=""; // we clear it just in case
              for (var i = 0, len = options.length; i < len; i++) {
                  objDiv.appendChild(createRadioButtonWithLabel(name, options[i], options[i]));
              }
          }

          /**
           * Get a group's selected node
           * @param groupname Name of the group
           * @return The radiobutton element that is checked, or null if none
           */

          function getSelectedNode(groupname) {
              var nodes = document.getElementById("radioDiv").childNodes;
              for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                  // nodes[i] is each label child of radioDiv
                  // we want its button to check if pressed
                  var radiobutton=nodes[i].firstChild;
                  if (radiobutton.checked) return radiobutton;
              }
              return null; // none selected
          }


          /**
           * Creates a label with a radiobutton and a text node
           * @param name Name of the group this radiobutton belongs to
           * @param label Label for the radiobutton
           * @param value Value for the radiobutton
           */

          function createRadioButtonWithLabel(groupname, label, value) {

              var objTextNode = document.createTextNode(label),
                  objLabel = document.createElement("label"),
                  objRadioButton = createRadioButton(groupname, value);

              objLabel.appendChild(objRadioButton);
              objLabel.appendChild(objTextNode);

              return objLabel;
          }

          /**
           * Creates a radio button
           * @param groupname Name of the group this radiobutton belongs to
           * @param value Value for the radiobutton
           */

          function createRadioButton(groupname, value) {
              var radioItem = document.createElement("input");
              radioItem.type = "radio";
              radioItem.name = groupname;
              radioItem.value = value;
              return radioItem;
          }

          //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

          function createStuff() {
              createRadioGroup("radioDiv", "coolMenu", ["Edit", "Delete", "Modify", "Modify a lot", "Have a beer", "Walk the dog", "f** my girlfriend"]);
          }

          function testStuff() {
              var nodeSelected = getSelectedNode("coolMenu");
              alert(nodeSelected.value);
          }

        </SCRIPT>  
    </HEAD>  
    <BODY>  
        <BUTTON onclick="createStuff()">Create Radio Buttons</BUTTON>
        <BUTTON onclick="testStuff()">Alert</BUTTON>
        <div id="radioDiv"></div>
    </BODY>  
</HTML>
```

------ OLDER MSG

you have a silly typo  and a little problem. This works:

```
        function test()
        {
            var b = document.getElementById("radioDiv").firstChild;

            // b is the LABEL OBJECT, its text is b.innerText

            var a=b.innerText
            alert(a);


            if (a=="Edit")
            {
                alert("Edit");
            }
            else if (a=="Delete")
            {
                alert("Delete");
            }
// THIS IS THE TYPO >>>   else()
            else 
            {
                alert("Try Again");
            }
        }
```

however, this code won't give you the selected label, but the first label (you are asking for `firstChild`)

If you want to find out which radio is selected using the structure you construct dynamically (which by the way is pretty complicated) you can define this handy function:

```
function isRadioButtonPressed(number) {
   return document.getElementById("rad"+number).checked;
}
```

because you have named your radiobuttons `rad1`, `rad2`, ...

so you can do:

```
var isEditSelected=isRadioButtonPressed(1); // will return true if edit is selected
var isDeleteSelected=isRadioButtonPressed(2);  // will return true if delete is selected
```

Some advices:

- You should create utility functions like isRadioButtonPressed to avoid writing over and over again long expressions with firstchild, document.getElementById, etc... as you see, the code can get very complicated to write simple things.
- You should use **FireBug** or **Chrome/Safari Developer tools**. If you use **chrome**, go to the "TOOLS" menu and select "developer tools". A window will appear and there you will see the errors of your code. If you do this with the original question you'll see how Chrome complains about a syntax error on the `else()` line. If you use **FireFox**, download **Firebug** plugin, is the same. It's a must for developing web pages.

More example functions:

```
 function createRadioButton(id, name, value) {
      var radioItem = document.createElement("input");  
      radioItem.type = "radio";  
      radioItem.name = name;
      radioItem.id = id;  
      radioItem.value = value; 
      return radioItem;
 }
```

Look how cool your createRadio is now:

```
 function createRadio() {

      var radioItem1=createRadioButton("rad1","radioGrp", "myradio1"),
          radioItem2=createRadioButton("rad2","radioGrp", "myradio2");

       .
       .
 }
```

Isn't is it much easier to read?

Hope it helps :)

Comment: oh wow... ur a master!!
You seems to got hold of the idea what i was trying to do in one go!...Can you please give me restructured code combining all the suggestion you've just made? Im a newbie and struggling to restructure my code the way you r suggesting... thanks a lot again